# Ruby unexpected keyword end, AND unexpected end of input

Tags: ruby

My code is as follows. If I remove the last `end`, it says `unexpected end of input`, if I put the `end` back in, it says `unexpected keyword end`. I cannot see anything wrong with the following code. Can you?

```
n = gets.chomp.to_i
array= Array.new(n, true)
while p<Math::sqrt(n) do
  i=p
  while (i<=n) do
    array[i] = false # not a prime
    i+=p
  end
  while array[p]!=true do
    p++
  end
end
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The increment operator (`++`):

```
p++
```

does not exists in Ruby. You meant:

```
p += 1
```

Comment: you are right. however, this does in no way make this a good error message :(

Comment: @mnagel you can't blame Ruby for that. Ruby can't handle an `end` after `+`. That's the issue that the error correctly complains about. The user is supposed to know the correct syntax. It gives the line on which the error happens. That should help you debug the problem.

Comment: @Mischa however, from a usability standpoint a warning "we just parsed `+` (unary plus) after `+` (binary plus) and while this is not an error it does not do what you want it to do" is preferable. of course this breaks backward compatibility with `+-++---+++1++2==3`

Comment: @Mischa, what you say is true, but it is also true that the way Ruby reports syntax errors is often cryptic and could be better. This is often the case with yacc-generated (actually most machine-generated) parsers.

Comment: Coming from other languages, I also used ++ on autopilot and had the same errors. It is a pretty dubious error message, but I guess it's my fault for thinking Ruby would respond to C. I'm ++ing question and answer so it comes up more frequently in search... could have spared an hour of my life.